# Google Apps Script: setSharing() not working for "anyone with link can view"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

What I try to achieve: use Google Apps Script to set the permissions and access of a file ("anyone with the link can view").

The issue: when I open the share URL the page says the user does not have permission to view the file.
It works fine again when I manually (using Drive web interface) unset the sharing permissions and set them again to "anyone with the link can view".

How I set the permissions and access:

```
myFile.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
```

When I check the result in the script, everything seems fine:

```
Logger.log(myFile.getSharingPermission());
--> [14-10-11 02:30:22:188 PDT] VIEW
Logger.log(myFile.getSharingAccess());
--> [14-10-11 02:30:22:366 PDT] ANYONE_WITH_LINK
```

When I check using the Drive web interface it is fine as well, sharing shows:
anyone with the link can view.

But when I access the URL shown in the sharing page, it says the user does not have permission and shows a button to request access.

[image]

When I finally use the Drive web interface to unset sharing and then manually set it again to "anyone with the link can view", the result is that indeed any user with the link can view the file.
The Logger output is the same for both the script way and the manual way of setting permission & access.

Suggestions?

**Update**: 
here is a complete code example. I create the file using **DocsList** so that the text file can be previewed, but the same result when I create the file using **DriveApp**. Rest of activities are done using **DriveApp**, which also is the only way to set permissions.

```
function testSharing() {
  var fileName = "test - file viewable by anyone with link.txt";
  var myFileDriveApp, myFileDocsList;

  // get directory of current spreadsheet
  var currentFileId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var fileSheet = DriveApp.getFileById(currentFileId);
  var directory = fileSheet.getParents().next();

  // check if file with that name already exists, if so use that one, otherwise create new file
  if (directory.getFilesByName(fileName).hasNext()) {
    // file found, get ID of first file with expected name
    myFileDriveApp = directory.getFilesByName(fileName).next();
    Logger.log("file already exists");
  } else {
    // file not found, create new empty Document with expected name
    //myFileDriveApp = directory.createFile(fileName, " "); // creates file that can not be previewed
    myFileDocsList = DocsList.getFolderById(directory.getId()).createFile(fileName, " "); // creates file that can be previewed
    myFileDriveApp = DriveApp.getFileById( myFileDocsList.getId() );
    Logger.log("created file --> access: "+ myFileDriveApp.getSharingAccess() +" - permission: "+ myFileDriveApp.getSharingPermission());
  }

  // set content of file
  var d = new Date();
  myFileDriveApp.setContent( d.toString() );
  Logger.log("set content  --> access: "+ myFileDriveApp.getSharingAccess() +" - permission: "+ myFileDriveApp.getSharingPermission());

  // set sharing access and permission
  myFileDriveApp.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
  Logger.log("setsharing   --> access: "+ myFileDriveApp.getSharingAccess() +" - permission: "+ myFileDriveApp.getSharingPermission());

  Logger.log("getUrl()   : "+ myFileDriveApp.getUrl().replace(/\/edit.*/,"/view"));
  Logger.log("share URL: "+ "https://drive.google.com/file/d/"+myFileDriveApp.getId()+"/view");
  //Logger.log("download url         : "+ myFileDriveApp.getDownloadUrl());
  //Logger.log("my Drive download url: "+ "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id="+ myFileDriveApp.getId());

}
```